# Check if object is empty or has values

Tags: php, object

I need to check if a object is empty or has values in PHP and after a research I come with this code:

```
$user = $this->client->findClientByLogin(array("login" => $user_data[0]->username));

if (!is_object($user) && (count(get_object_vars($user)) < 0)) {
    $this->client->addClient(array("login" => $user_data[0]->username, "password" => $password));
}
```

But even if `$user` is a empty object the `addClient()` is not executed since the condition doesn't work right. Can any give me some advice on this?

**Edit: Test1**

I did some testing using this code:

```
echo "Count ".count(get_object_vars($user));
echo "Is object ".!is_object($user);
var_dump($user);
die();
```

And the result was:
    Count: 
    Is Object: 1

```
object(stdClass)[78]
  public 'clientsshared' => 
    object(stdClass)[160]
      public 'id_client' => int 44
      public 'login' => string 'reynierperez-mira' (length=17)
      public 'password' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'web_password' => string '09bb0def8de1262ac9e5a9b8a5935771' (length=32)
      public 'type' => int 8389121
      public 'id_tariff' => int 2
      public 'account_state' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
      public 'tech_prefix' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'id_reseller' => int -1
      public 'type2' => int 0
      public 'type3' => int 0
      public 'id_intrastate_tariff' => int -1
      public 'id_currency' => int 1
      public 'codecs' => int 19
      public 'primary_codec' => int 2
      public 'free_seconds' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'id_tariff_vod' => int 0
      public 'video_codecs' => int 0
      public 'video_primary_codec' => int 0
      public 'fax_codecs' => int 0
      public 'fax_primary_codec' => int 0
      public 'id_cli_map' => int 0
      public 'id_dial_plan' => int 1
      public 'id_dial_plan_map' => int 1
      public 'id_pbx_company' => int 0
```

So that tell me that the user `reynierperez-mira` already exists so I should not enter on conditional since I'll not add any user, but if user doesn't exists then I'll add by entering on the conditional. What is the right conditional on this case?

**Test2: user doesn't exists**

Ok, I delete all users so `findClientByLogin()` return a empty object. I test in this way:

```
$user = $this->client->findClientByLogin(array("login" => $user_data[0]->username));

echo "Count " . count(get_object_vars($user));
echo "Is object " . is_object($user);
echo "-----------";
var_dump($user);
die();
```

And this was the output:

```
Count 0
Is object 1
-----------

object(stdClass)[78]
```

So I changed the condition to:

```
if (is_object($user) && (count(get_object_vars($user)) === 0)) { ...
```

And now it works!

Comment: `count()` can never return less than 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `OR`, not `AND` to combine the conditions. And `count()` can never return less than `0`; if the object has no properties, the count will be `0`.

```
if(!is_object($user) || count(get_object_vars($user)) == 0) {
    $this->client->addClient(array("login" => $user_data[0]->username, "password" => $password));
}
```

Comment: I can't understand that output, it makes no sense.

Comment: Well the problem is when `reynierperez-mira` doesn't exists then `$user` should be an empty object and then this line `$this->client->addClient(array("login" => $user_data[0]->username, "password" => $password));` need to be executed but it's not working not with your suggestion not with my code

Comment: The first two lines are doing the exact opposite of what they should. I don't see how `var_dump()` can say it's an object, but `is_object()` says it isn't.

Comment: Hmmm so how I execute the line if `$user` is a empty object?

Comment: The code I posted is what SHOULD work. Something very weird is happening in your case, and I have no idea how to deal with it. Check very carefully for typos. Make sure you don't have any Unicode characters that look like ASCII characters.

Comment: Make sure you have error reporting enabled and look for notices about undefined variables.